# Ошибка No media type information после загрузки Rewarded Ad

Tags: admob, ads

Имплементирую в свое приложение Rewarded Ad (при этом есть и работают Native Ad и Banner Ad).После вызова метода RewardedAd.load загрузка произошла, идентификатор рекламного объявления присвоен, но происходит циклическая ошибка, которая прекращается только после закрытия приложения. Рекламное объявление не показывается.
Вот что выдает:
[image: Ошибка после загрузки Rewarded Ad]

Метод показа (show) при этом еще не вызван.